# php turn [$id] to include($id.'.php');

Tags: php

I would like to include a content inside an other content in order to have a nested architecture.

In my wysiwyg I want to write something like this:

```
This is the beginning of my article
[99]
This is the end of my article
```

As a result I'm trying to get the equivalent of

```
This is the beginning of my article
include(99.php);
This is the end of my article
```

How to do that? with a callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to replace the pattern `[99]` and replace by the include:

```php
$str = 'This is the beginning of my article
[99]
This is the end of my article';

// replace only the pattern "[number]":
$str = preg_replace_callback('~\[(\d+)\]~', function($matches) {
    // define the filename (here a file in the same folder)
    $file = __dir__ . '/' . $matches[1] . '.php';
    // check if exists
    if (!file_exists($file)) return '--not-exists--';
    // include and get as string:
    ob_start();
    include($file);
    $out = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $out;

}, $str);

echo $str;
```

Will outputs something like:

```
This is the beginning of my article
This is the content of 99.php.
This is the end of my article
```

Comment: excellllllent. exactly what I needed. clever answer to a dumb question THX

Comment: You're welcome @Morse :) Not a dumb question, just knowledge to increase ;)